# Writing solutions of inequalities: $3<x$ versus $x>3$

Tags: inequality, notation, proof-writing, education

My son wrote a solution to a number line graph as 3 < x instead of what his teacher said was the correct answer of x > 3.  When he brought his paper back in to bring it up he was told that the variable had to come first.  I can't imagine why this is so - is there any precedence for this one-sided interpretation?  As a former math teacher I am perplexed why someone would not allow for an alternate writing (albeit an odd one).

Comment: They're mathematically equivalent. Writing it one way or the other is just a convention. I can understand explaining the convention to help with consistency, but considering it incorrect seems...well, incorrect.

Comment: I wonder how the teacher would have wanted the answer expressed had it turned out that $x$ also had to be less than $4$.

Comment: I think it is insensible of the teachter to say that this was wrong. Perhaps the teacher told them as a 'classroom convention' that they should write the variable on the left side, but I see no sense in doing so, especially when you work with graphical tools as number lines it sometimes makes sense to write it on or the other way.

Comment: You may be interested in another Stack Exchange site, [matheducators.se]

Comment: In programming, something like "$3 < x$" is known as a [Yoda condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). It works, but some people find it annoying.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yes, and in programming I would often write `3 < x and x < 5` to mimic the maths $3 < x < 5$.

Answer (score 2):

$3<x \iff x>3$.

That is, the statements $3<x$ and $x>3$ are equivalent.

Your son's teacher is wrong.

---

I personally prefer to put the variable first, but, by no means is *not* doing so wrong. It's just a matter of convention.

The reason for the teacher's wanting to put the variable first is that  it's more natural to express the solution, $x$, in terms of 3 in this case. We don't really care about what 3 is in terms of anything else; we care about what $x$ is, which is why we usually put $x$ first.

Answer (score 1):

The object of the sentence $3<x$ is 3 but really the object we are interested in is $x$ so $x>3$ is preferable.  Also, graphing $3<x$ is conceptually more difficult at that level and so the preference is $x>3$.  A frequent error is to graph the wrong solution, showing that the student doesn't understand the answer.  His answer is correct, just not preferred. As in 1/2 is preferred over 2/4.

Comment: I don't think your final sentence is a very good example although I see where you're going with it. In my view $3<x$ can't be simplified, whereas $2/4$ can be simplified to $1/2$. An alternative analogy might be $2^{-1}$=$1/2$ but it's normally preferable to write $1/2$.

Comment: Surely graphing $3 < x$ is easier than $x > 3$.

Comment: @goblin The responses from students would suggest not. When they have $x>3$ their graphs are correct while the students that use $3<x$ often have the incorrect graph.

Comment: @PaulSundheim, fair enough.